# Как можно реализовать отправку уведомлений на андроид смартфон при обновлении материалов сайта?

Tags: android, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть андроид приложение для сайта. Есть образовательный сайт, наполняющийся материалами. Старые материалы время от времени редактируются и дополняются. Интересует, возможно ли реализовать оправку уведомлений на смартфон при правках старых материалов.
Рассылка уведомлений при публикации новых статей не интересует. RSS лента не помогает
Возможно, следует взаимодействовать с БД сайта и на основе операции UPDATE что-либо делать? Проблема в том, что mysql и андроид достаточно тяжело подружить + проблемы с безопасностью(???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым простым решением кажется проверка, инициализируемая приложением. Сделайте некоторый RestAPI с, возможно, одним единственным методом. Этот метод получает на вход число - время публикации самой старой известной клиенту записи. Метод собирает все данные старше этого времени в некотором формате и отдает клиенту, клиент сохраняет. Если Возможно изменение данных вместо даты создания используем дату редактирования. Если материалы могут удаляться надо придумывать костыль чтобы удалять их у клиента. Теперь при запуске приложения оно проверяет есть ли новые записи. Если есть - качает их и сохраняет на телефоне, после чего допускает юзера до просмотра. Так не придется mysql дружить с андроидом, retrofit и gson справятся

Если надо, чтобы пользователь получал уведомление о новых материалах даже если не запускал ваше приложение - придется при публикации материала создавать оповещение [через Firebase](https://habr.com/ru/post/345942/), но общая суть останется той же